# docker with nginx and gunicorn not opening in browser

Tags: docker, nginx

I am new to `Docker` and setting up `docker` to run `Django` application using `gunicorn` and `nginx`

my configuration files are

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: "myapp-nginx"
    ports:
      - "10080:80"
      - "10443:43"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./static_cdn:/static
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: "myapp-dev"
    command: ./start.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./static_cdn:/static
    ports:
      - "9010"
    depends_on:
      - db
    expose:
      - "9010"
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: "myapp-db"
```

**config/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
upstream web {
    ip_hash;
    server web:9010;
}

server {
    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web;
    }
    listen 9010;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

**start.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Start Gunicorn processes
echo --: Starting application build
echo --: Creating migration
python3 manage.py makemigrations
echo ------: makemigrations complete
echo --: Running migration
python3 manage.py migrate
echo ------: migrate complete
echo --: Running collectstatic
python3 manage.py collectstatic <<<yes
echo ------: collectstatic complete
echo --: Starting Gunicorn.
gunicorn koober.wsgi:application \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:9010 \
    --workers 3
```

running docker using

```
docker-compose up --build
```

It runs successfully with output as

[image]

**Here gunicorn is successfully started at `0.0.0.0:9010`. But unable to visit the application using browser.**

I tried following address in browser

1. 127.0.0.1:9010
2. 127.0.0.1:10080
3. 127.0.0.1
4. localhost:9010
5. localhost:10080
6. localhost
7. 0.0.0.0:9010
8. 0.0.0.0:10080
9. 0.0.0.0

But none of them is working.

> Edit 2: output of `docker ps -a`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:9010;
}
server {

 listen       10080;

 location / {
    proxy_pass http://web;
 }     
}
```

Nginx should listen on **10080** port because in your compose file you have exposed port 80 to 10080 port.

and then try **http://localhost:10080** or **http://machine-ip-address:10080**

here is the blog which I have written to explain how Docker + Nginx + Web application work together.

https://rohanjmohite.wordpress.com/2017/08/02/how-to-configure-docker-with-nginx-and-php-application/

Source code 
https://github.com/RohanMohite/Docker-Nginx-PHP/blob/master/server_nginx/conf/server.conf

Comment: I tried with it but no success. I find the ip address using `ipconfig getifaddr en0` which returned `192.168.31.13`, I tried with this IP address too but no success.

Comment: I have setup `valet` in my mac-machine which is using nginx and running as core service. Is it effecting this?

Comment: One more thing - in your docker-compose file for web, can you please try ports:
      - "9010:9010" and remove expose tag.

Comment: Yes I added **9010:9010** to `web` and its working at `127.0.0.1:9010`. But could not understand the flow of ports. We have added `listen 10080;` to nginx conf and it's working on `9010`. Can you explain it's working.

Comment: it should work on 10080 port, can you please cross-check your Nginx config file. At the end, you should be able to hit 127.0.0.1:10080 url and it should automatically re-direct you to the web server.

Comment: I cross check and everything is same as yours. This time I just copy-paste your setting to prevent any typo and still it is listening to `9010` and not at `10080`

Comment: can you please send me the output of docker ps -a command, please?

Comment: please check `Edit 2` in question

Comment: docker output seems to be alright, I just made little changes in your config file, can you please try that? what we are doing actually NGINX will listen on port 10080 and if any request came, it will transfer it to the Web container web:9010 port.

Comment: this is my NGINX configuration https://github.com/RohanMohite/Docker-Nginx-PHP/blob/master/server_nginx/conf/server.conf                                        I am having two containers which communicate via NGINX.

Comment: Hey, it seems nginx is now working. I removed the line `- ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d` from `services: nginx:` inside `docker-compose.yml` and it is still working on **9010**. I event tried with changing settings in nginx.conf file but no error is there.